# In Swift, how can I append a URL with a string from a UISearchbar and automatically open it in Safari?

Tags: ios, swift, url, uisearchbar

I'm working on an app that will have a search bar where you enter text.

I'd like the app then to open "www.example.com/"entered text from search bar" but the only thing that seams to happen is it actually attempts to open www.example.com/dncode (which is not a real URL).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

//connection that ties search bar in view to input for viewcontroller

@IBOutlet weak var searchbar: UISearchBar!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchbar.delegate = self
}
//activates keyboard etc when searchbar clicked
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchbar: UISearchBar) {
    searchbar.resignFirstResponder()
    //(dncode) is string that will equal text as entered into search     bar

    let dncode = String()

    searchbar.text! = dncode

    if let url = URL (string: "https://www.example.com/(dncode)")
    {


        //this section to check and auto open URL in default browser     "Safari"
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
    {

        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what is dncode in your code, it's just en empty string ? Can you  give more precisions ? What url do you want to open in Safari ?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the text of search bar equal to your dncode variable and not viceversa.
You have to change your implementation:

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchbar: UISearchBar) {
    searchbar.resignFirstResponder()
    //(dncode) is string that will equal text as entered into search bar

    guard let dncode = searchbar.text else { return }

    if let url = URL (string: "https://www.example.com/(dncode)") {
        //this section to check and auto open URL in default browser     "Safari"
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You also must replace:  if let url = URL (string: "https://www.example.com/(dncode)") by if let url = URL (string: "https://www.example.com/\(dncode)")

Answer (score 0):

You must replace:

```
let dncode = String()
searchbar.text! = dncode
if let url = URL (string: "https://www.example.com/(dncode)")
```

by

```
 guard let dncode = searchbar.text else { return }   
 if let url = URL (string: "https://www.example.com/\(dncode)")
```